# nginx - unable to use (different)certificate for second site

Tags: ssl, nginx, certbot

I originally used certbot for my first site(default)'s cert. All was well and it has worked wonderfully for the past 6months.
Recently I've tried to add another site to my server , and the problem occurs when I try to certify it. (It works fine running on http - using port 80).

I followed the exact same steps as before using certbot to generate the ssl-cert (albeit changing the names), and I had no issues.

However now when I add that cert for site2 to, it redirects to default & shows as not-secure in the url-bar.
If I try go to default, it works fine and is still certified.

I'm certain it is an issue with the certificate for site2, but i'm not sure where the issue lies?

My original website "default" is a php script.
However the second site "site2" is a html script.

Default's code;

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server ;

    listen [::]:80 default_server  ipv6only=on;
    server_name default.com www.default.com;
            return 301 https://www.default.com$request_uri;


    }

server{
 listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
 listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
 include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-default.com.conf;
 include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;



       location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }


     root /var/www/default.com/site;
 index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
   server_name _;

    location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

      }



   location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
     fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    }


 location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }

}
```

site2's code;

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name site2.com www.site2.com;
    return 302 https://www.site2.com$request_uri;
}
server{
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name _;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-site2.com.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;

     location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }


    root /var/www/site2.com/;
    index index.html;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }



}
```

sudo nginx -t output;

```
  [warn] "ssl_stapling" ignored, issuer certificate not found
  nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "_" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
  nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "_" on [::]:443, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "default.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.default.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, 
ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "default.com" on [::]:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.default.com" on [::]:80, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

params.conf contains;

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_tickets off;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 5s;
# disable HSTS header for now
#add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; 
preload";
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
```

ssl.site2.com.conf has the locations of the privkey and fullchain. (same format & location as default's just change of names..)

*Checking the "not-secure" in the url-bar, states the cert for site2 is issued to default

Answer (score 0):

`server_name _` should not be used on ssl hosts unless there is only one virtual host; you should set the explicit name in each server section.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you have 2 or more configuration files where you set one value in `server_name` for the same port. As I can see, one of these files are `default`. Try to check `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` for existing sites.

Try to remove line `server_name _;` from both `::443` configs and it should work.